# How to create an IS_A relationship using Microsoft Access Relationships Tool

Tags: ms-access

I was unable to find a clear answer of how to create an IS_A relationship in Access.

There was the same question here, but without a concise answer:
[IS_A relationship primary key validation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40588805/is-a-relationship-primary-key-validation-rules)

I have the entity Employee, and two sub-entities Loan_Officer and Branch_Manager. It's a school example of an IS_A relationship really.

[image]

I've managed to create A relationship, but there needs to be a constraint that an employee must be either a Loan Officer or a Branch Manager, but can not be both. Now, I can't figure out how to do this, because what ever I do, I can assign the same Employee_ID in both sub-entity tables at once.

I've connected the tables via the PK, as it's shown here:
[image]

Now, this table design is just something I've done, in order to be able to connect them via a one-to-one relationship. I had to set the PK of Loan_Officer to "Number" and not "AutoNumber", in order to be able to connect them. The other option is to have a separate PK in Loan_Officer, like "Loan_Officer_ID", and a foreign key, "Employee_ID" in the Loan_Officer table, but the results are again the same (also according to the ER Diagram, the sub-entities don't have a separate PK).

[image]
[image]

Comment: I would create one entity instead of 2 - Officer with own autonumber PK, field OfficerType with 2 possible values (Loan and Manager) and FK to Employee table.

Comment: I was also considering that. In this simple case it actually could be a best option. But in some cases where the two different subclass entities have a lot of different attributes, we would have a lot of null values in the respective fields?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. This is not a feature of the Access database.

You can create `CHECK` constraints to check for such conditions, but those don't offer features to cascade operations.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27982995/7296893) for an example on how to create a `CHECK` constraint.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as an 'Is A' relationship in databases between tables.  This is instead a field in the Employee table or Employee History Table.

The issue of 'can't be both' is a matter of validation logic.  Where this validation logic is applied is probably at the form object level (during data entry), not the table level (no data should ever be entered directly into tables by end users).

Comment: Thank you, I think I might implement it in the forms, as you said, the data shouldn't be entered directly into tables anyway

Answer (score 1):

Look into [Access Data Macros](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-data-macro-b1b94bca-4f17-47ad-a66d-f296ef834200?ocmsassetID=HA010378170&CorrelationId=f1a96e4d-102a-44f8-b623-0a59315dcb27&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) . They can be used like SQL triggers firing off when a record is INSERTed, UPDATEed, DELETEed etc.